# expo and react native: Redirect back to the running app after login from identity server in webview

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo, deep-linking

I have an react native application initially running on expo client. I am using the webview to login to the identity server and redirect back to the application. It running fine within expo. In the standalone android application, it does redirect back to the application but it looks like it run the again again instead of going to my Linking.addEventListener which i have it to extract the data from redirection.

My Linking function:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
loginSrc =  AUTHORIZATION_URL + "?" + getHybridRequestBody();
console.log(loginSrc);
Linking.addEventListener("url", this._onExtractCode);
```

}

componentWillUnmount = () =>{
    Linking.removeEventListener("url", this._onExtractCode);
  }

My modal which open the webview

```
<Modal visible={this.state.showLoginModal} transparent={true}> 
            <View style={[styles.container, {flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white"}]}>
              <TouchableOpacity style={{width: 35, height: 35}} onPress={this.onModalClose}> 
                <Ionicons name="ios-close" size={30} color={Colors.Teal} ></Ionicons>  
              </TouchableOpacity>   
              <WebView source={ { uri:loginSrc}} ></WebView>

            </View>
          </Modal>
```

The url for login:

```
io.testing.is://?callback=authentication
```

app.json:

```
"scheme": "io.testing.is",
```

The android standalone app does redirect to the application but it's not calling the Linking.addEventListener callback _onExtractCode.

For ios, I have no idea what will happen

Comment: Did you setting AndroidManifest in android?

Comment: No the app is not ejected... I just build using expo build:android but i think it called Linking.getInitialUrl method though. Now i am testing whether it will get things i wanted. I am not sure how to test on iOS though until i publish to appStore

Answer (score 0):

Call back the riser as shown below.

it’s worth noting that the callback for `Linking.addEventListener('url', this._onExtractCode)` receives an event and not a url string directly. To get the url from that you will need to do `event.url`. So, instead you can do

```
Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => this._onExtractCode(url))
```

Comment: Expo itself did have on his own https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/

Comment: On my android: it reload the application and called Linking.getInitialUrl instead of addEventListener but the app is already in foreground. is it because the old android i have.

Comment: It looks like it open up a new instance of the app instead of using the existing app